# Remove/Redirect index.php from url to prevent duplicate urls

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

*Please read the question carefully before marking as duplicate.*

We all know, that using in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

we can redirect all traffic to `index.php` so we can create friendly urls and have one front controller.

Although the question is connected to `mod_rewrite` the problem is described for Laravel.

The following `.htaccess` comes by default with Laravel 4 and it works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

If we run url `mydomain.com/something` and have set that route for `something` properly, some controller will be launched. It works fine so far.

However in `Laravel 4` we will be able to reach the same route using `mydomain.com/index.php/something`. Probably using Laravel  url creating we will have no urls with `index.php` in url but there is some other problem.

For example if our competition would like to make us some harm, they can simple put in Internet single links for urls to `mydomain.com/index.php/something`, `mydomain.com/index.php/something2` and so on and search engines will see duplicate urls.

Of course if we have our custom PHP application, we can do it in PHP without a problem checking simply `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and make 301 redirection. We can of course do the same in Laravel but we have to write this code in PHP each time and probably some developers could say it is bad practice to do it in PHP.

Question is simple: how can I redirect in .htaccess all urls that contain index.php to to the same url without index.php?

Example urls that should be redirected:

1. `mydomain.com/index.php/something` should be redirected to `mydomain.com/something`  (something could be anything - can contain any characters)
2. `mydomain.com/index.php` should be redirected to `mydomain.com`
3. `mydomain.com/index.php?anything` should be redirected to `mydomain.com` (anything can contain any characters)
4. `mydomain.com/index.phpanything` should be redirected to `mydomain.com` anything can contain any characters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Insert these rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: I found some problems here. 1) I don't understand why RewriteCond in both rules are the same. 2) `mydomain.com/index.php/something` redirects to `mydomain.com//something` (double slash) 3) `mydomain.com/index.php?anything` redirects to `mydomain.com/?anything` and not `mydomain.com` Other 2 rules `mydomain.com/index.phpanything` and `mydomain.com/index.php` work as expected

Comment: check updated rules now. `RewriteCond` line is same but URI matching pattern is different in 2 rules.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Remember to change `302` to `301` to make it permanent redirect.

Comment: Yes, I noticed you used 302 redirection instead of 301. But by the way it's quite strange that frameworks don't care about duplicated urls at all as I showed in this question. They should provide those (or similar) rules by default in their `.htaccess` file

Comment: Actually 301 is used mostly for SEO and reducing load on your server as browser will permanently cache it. But one needs to be very careful also using 301 as sometimes due to mistakes they let browsers cache bad URLs.

Comment: Just want to say, that this code works perfectly in 2020. Laravel 6.x

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours I write below code for me and its 100% working

## Redirect index.php to non index.php

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I redirect in .htaccess all urls that contain index.php to to
>   the same url without index.php?

Add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work. `mydomain.com/index.php` redirects my url to `mydomain.com/home/testsite/public_html` so showing my file path in url

Answer (score 0):

For Nginx, here is the rules :

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? redirect;
    rewrite ^/(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem to force https & remove index.php from the url in Kohan 2.3

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]


RewriteRule ^(application|system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```