# Remove/Redirect public/index.php from url to prevent duplicate urls

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello i am facing issue to remove the public/index.php from url. [Remove/Redirect index.php from url to prevent duplicate urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105872/remove-redirect-index-php-from-url-to-prevent-duplicate-urls)
This link really helps me to remove index.php form url but i am not able to remove public/index.php from url. Here is my below htacces code

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #REmove index.php from url starts
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
 #Remove index.php from url ends

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when i add this below code to remove public/index.php in htaccess its not working :-

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)public/index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)public/index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Example urls that should be redirected:

1. `mydomain.com/public/index.php/something` should be redirected to `mydomain.com/something`  (something could be anything - can contain any characters)
2. `mydomain.com/public/index.php` should be redirected to `mydomain.com`
3. `mydomain.com/index.php?anything` should be redirected to `mydomain.com?anything` (anything can contain any characters)

Pleae help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: In your 4th condition `mydomain.com/public/index.phpanything should be redirected to mydomain.com anything can contain any characters)` are you hitting `mydomain.com` in your browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: mydomain.com is just example for security purpose i am not sharing the domain name here

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have removed the 4th condition

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `public/` also?

Comment: yes @anubhava its there

Comment: i have two htaccess one is at root and other is at inside public folder

Comment: i am using laravel farmework when we deploy the prject at server by default public is coming onurl that i have removed already. but left with to remove public/index.php from url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this rule inside `public/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/index\.php(?:[/?](\S+))?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

# other rules below this line
```

Additionally use this code in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks very very much its working pretty fine ..... i am having facing one problem for internal urls mydomain.com/public/index.php/testing its converting to mydomain.com//testing its coming double slashes  after domain

Comment: i have added the code at public htaccess file

Comment: its still coming @anubhava

Comment: It's not coming anymore, you might have old browser cache. Test with `mydomain.com/public/index.php/qwert1234`

Comment: yes working now thanks.... just now faced one more issue mydomain.com/public/qwert1234 to mydomain.com/qwert1234

Comment: can we do this :- mydomain.com/public/qwert1234 to mydomain.com/qwert1234

Comment: thank you, your answer fixed my nightmare